# Azure repos for teams subscription. specific branch updates

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams

I'm creating a connector to post master branch updates to a channel in MS teams. I setup the entire flow, but unable to select specific branch from dropdown when creating a subscription. [Any] is selected by default and I don't see any other branches. The event I'm trying is Pull request merge attempted.[Azure repos for teams subsciption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Bgb.jpg). I'm able to see data fine in other dropdowns. When I check the web teams api response, dropdown values are not received.
[choices dropdown api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My7Ld.jpg)
Steps I followed to create subscription

1. Azure repos signin
2. Azure repos subscribe <repo_url>
3. Azure repos subscriptions -> add subscription -> select event
   -> select repository -> cant change target branch in drop down here

Notifications works fine. I'm getting updates on all PR's, but to every branch. I want only master branch updates.

Should I enable something to get branches list in the dropdown?

Comment: Can you please check whether you have required permissions and properly configured the subscription.

Comment: Yes I'm project administrator in azure devops and also enabled Third-party application access via OAuth. I'm able to see all other data fine, like requested member group and reviewer includes group. Only target branch values are empty. should i enable anything else? Updated the question with steps i followed to create subscription.

Comment: we are also able to repro this issue, we will check internally and get back to you.

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same, we will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT - is there any update on this issue? We are also facing the same issue where I am not able to narrow down notifications for  build failures just to one specific branch.

Comment: @JigarSheth the drop down to select a branch doesn't work, it shows [any]. 
After selecting Repository -> you can just type your branch name in place of any. we are doing this for master and dev branches to get notified when ever code is pushed.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT how do you configure and run commands once it is installed? I tried looking here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/integrations/repos-teams?view=azure-devops but it wasn't helpful. Not clear where to run the commands.

Comment: @OliverNilsen Go to any teams channel and type at rate Azure repos and select the command you want. you should run at rate Azure repos Signin, then configure an event using at rate Azure repos subscribe to enable notifications.